# VScode setup with ROS and auto complete

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, ros

I am struggling to configure VSCode with ROS to have the auto-complete function.
I am used to using VSCode with Qt and OpenCV and everything worked fine.
For example, for OpenCV, I just edited `c_cpp_propreties.json` like this:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "gnu11",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

The auto-complete for OpenCV works fine then (I have the *C++ IntelliSense extension*).
But then, as soon as I try to specify the `include` folder from ROS in the `c_cpp_propreties.json`, nothing works anymore, not even the OpenCV auto-completion:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2",
            "/opt/ros/melodic/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "gnu11",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

It's like ROS is blocking everything. What am I doing wrong? I specify that I click on "Open Folder" in VSCode and browse for the ROS package to load it.
I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Do you have any news on this? I am also trying to get this to work? The ROS extension doesn't quite cut it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a problem when using the IntelliSense with ROS. It would simply not search the `ros` namespace, no matter what I did. So I thought of changing the `cppStandard` (in file `c_cpp_properties.json`) to `gnu++11` (it's only for IntelliSense anyways). It immediately started working.

Here are the results with `cppStandard` set to `gnu++14`
[image]

Here are the results with `cppStandard` set to `gnu++11`
[image]

I have even tried `gnu++17`, but that too gave limited success. Looks like `gnu++11` worked best.

I also tried what Richard had to say in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62921325/5836037). It works without having to change anything else.

Comment: you are wizard dude, honestly, this is black magic :P

Answer (score 5):

You need to generate compile_commands.json and put that in your vscode work directory. This file will tell vscode linter where to look. This needs to be regenerated if you create new files or your compile instruction in CMakeLists.txt changes (i.e new libraries)

I made a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/b9vXhlJllsE) to demo this

I also answered this in a similar post on a reddit: [Has anyone got Visual Studio to work properly with ROS?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/hqud2a/has_anyone_got_visual_studio_to_work_properly/). I've added the answer i wrote for that below;

If you use catkin_make, when you compile,

`cakin_make -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1`

A `compile_commands.json` will then appear in your build folder after compiling.

If you use catkin tools, because the build system is different, you will have a run a script after building to merge the individual `compile_commands.json` into one

[See the issue here for script.](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/551)

You can then restart VScode, and it will prompt you and ask if you want to use it when it starts. If it didnt prompt you for whatever reason,

> [In the "Advanced" section of the Configuration UI, you can supply the path to your compile_commands.json and the extension will use the compilation information listed in that file to configure IntelliSense.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-get-intellisense-to-work-correctly)

Basically, the steps are:

1. cakin_make -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1
2. move compile_commands from catkin_ws/build under your vscode work directory, i usually have it under catkin_ws/src, personal preference
3. Point vscode to your compile commands.

ROS should work properly from here.

Edit: added steps from answer made in another post

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it. Answers that are little more than a link [may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Hi. If I have let's say `ros::NodeHandle n;` and then I would like my autocomplete to `n.` find my `n` related methods, attributes etc. what should I do ? I mention that I'm using VScode on ubuntu and I've installed autocomplete plugin, and also I've installed ROS plugin. For the moment I only get `n.` -> no suggestions.

Comment: Also, what is `Point vscode to your compile commands.` this ?

Comment: if you followed the steps shown in the video, you should have autocomplete to `n`.

Comment: `Point vscode to your compile command` refers to doing `you can then restart VScode, and it will prompt you...`

Answer (score 1):

In the file `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` (generated by the [VSCode ROS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros#review-details)), try to change from `"cppStandard": "gnu++14"` to `"cppStandard": "c++14"`.

ROS is using the [c++14 standard](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic), so specifying `gnu++14` seems to break things. This was deduced from [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/341313/what-happens-if-i-use-c-17-features-in-my-ros-nodes/).

An [issue](https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/issues/336) exists about this.